# Ativar e desativar um while com o keyboard python

Tags: python, teclado

Fiz esse código com a intenção de que ao segurar a tecla 'q', é como se eu estivesse a pressionando e despressionando várias vezes.

Mas não to conseguindo fazer com que ao eu apertar uma sequencia de tecla por exemplo 'ctrl+space' ative essa função, e ao clicar 'ctrl+space' novamente ou outra sequência, desative a função.

```
import keyboard as kb
from time import sleep

onoff = None
while True:
    ativar = kb.is_pressed('ctrl+space')
    desativar = kb.is_pressed('p')

    if ativar is True:
        onoff = 1
    sleep(0.05)
    if desativar is True:
        onoff = 0

    while onoff:
        a = kb.is_pressed('q')

        if a is True:
            kb.send('q')
            print(ativar)
            print(desativar)
            sleep(0.02)
```

Answer (score -3):

Não sei se entendi bem o que você quer, mas se entendi certo você quer que, ao pressionar ctrl+space ele ative e ao pressionar p ele desative a verificação se a tecla q está sendo pressionada, ou seja, se a função for desativada ele nem verificar se pressionou q até ativar a função novamente, é isso? Caso positivo desse jeito que você fez creio que não vá funcionar mesmo. Uma solução que vejo é usar loop com condicionais. Por exemplo:
import keyboard as kb
from time import sleep
onoff=None
while True:
if onoff and !kb.is_pressed("p"):
//verifique aqui se a tecla q foi pressionada
sleep(0.05)
elif !onoff:
if kb.is_pressed("ctrl+space"):
onoff=True
sleep(0.05)
else:
onoff=False
sleep(0.05)

Ou seja, ele entra num loop infinito, lá dentro o primeiro if verifica se onoff é verdadeiro, e se a tecla p, que é utilizada para interromper a verificação não é pressionada. caso ambas as condições sejam verdade, verifica se a tecla q foi pressionada e usa a lógica aí que você desenvolver. Caso contrário, elif, se onoff for False (!onoff), ele verifica se a combinação de teclas ctrl+space foi pressionada, pois caso positivo, tem que colocar o onoff em 1, pois está ativando a função de verificação de se a tecla q foi pressionada. Caso contrário, só um else, pois as outras duas condições possíveis já foram tratadas, se onoff for verdadeiro e a tecla p não tiver sido pressionada e se onoff for falso, ou seja, a última condição possível é se onoff for verdadeiro e a tecla p for pressionada, nesse caso coloca onoff como False. Em cada iteração do loop essas condicionais são aplicadas, para ver em qual dos casos a iteração se encaixa. Notar que coloquei um sleep(0.05) em cada condicional, pois como o loop aí nesse caso é infinito, se ficar iterando sem tempo de espera é bem provável que trave o programa.
outra coisa, não sei se respondi corretamente ao que você deseja, pois no código original, os whiles estão um independente do outro, mas acho que entendi você quis fazer como se eles executassem em paralelo. Mas, daí se o sistema ficar enviando q com o kb.send a tecla sempre vai ficar pressionada até pressionar p para parar, não sei se é isso que você queria. Caso seja, tem que fazer da mesma forma que fiz acima, em um while só com condicionais e, caso necessário na sua lógica loops aninhados. Pois como você fez em 2 whiles sem utilizar threads nem nada do tipo, os 2 whiles o while True e o while onoff não funcionarão em paralelo, funcionarão um de cada vez, e como você não definiu algum ponto com break para o while True, ele nunca entrará no while onoff.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Fiz de um jeito aqui e deu certo da forma que queria:

```
import keyboard as kb
from time import sleep

onoff = None

while True:
    ativar = kb.is_pressed('ctrl+space')

    if ativar is True:
        print('on')
        onoff = 1

    sleep(0.05)

    while onoff:
        desativar = kb.is_pressed('p')

        if desativar is True:
            print('off')
            onoff = 0

        a = kb.is_pressed('q')

        if a is True:
            kb.send('q')
            sleep(0.02)
```